# Deleting a row if it contains a string in a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble deleting rows in text file that contains a string in one column. My code so far is not able to delete the row, but it's able to read the text file and save it as a CSV file into separate columns. But the rows are not getting deleted.

This is what the values in that column looks like:

```
Ship To or Bill To
------------------
3000000092-BILL_TO
3000000092-SHIP_TO
3000004000_SHIP_TO-INAC-EIM
```

And there are 20 more columns and 50,000k plus rows. So essentially I'm trying to delete **all** the rows that contain strings `'INAC'` or `'EIM'`.

```
import csv

my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
remove_words = ['INAC','EIM']

with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, \
     open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
        if not any(remove_word in line for remove_word in remove_words):
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the `csv.reader` object returns the rows of the file as lists of individual column values, so the "in" test is checking to see whether any of the individual values in that list is equal to a `remove_word`.

A quick fix would be to try

```
        if not any(remove_word in element
                      for element in line
                      for remove_word in remove_words):
```

because this will be true if any field in the line contains any of the `remove_words`.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have pointed out, the reason your code doesn't work is because each `line in csv.reader` is actually a list of column values, so the `remove_word in line` checks to see if any of them is exactly equal to one of the `remove_words` — which is apparently never `True`.

If you only need to check for the words in one column there's no reason to check all of them. The following will only check one column's value and so should be significantly faster than checking all 20 or more of them in every row of your file.

```
import csv

my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file_name = "cleanNVG.csv"
ONE_COLUMN = 1
remove_words = ['INAC', 'EIM']

with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, \
     open(cleaned_file_name, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='|'):
        column = row[ONE_COLUMN]
        if not any(remove_word in column for remove_word in remove_words):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line output by the csv reader is a list of strings, not a string, so your list comprehension is checking if 'INAC' or 'EIM' is one of the members of the list, i.e:

```
'INAC' in ['3000004000_SHIP_TO-INAC-EIM', ...]
```

Which is always false, since 'in' looks for exact matches when called on a list. If you want to check whether the string is present anywhere in the line, you don't need a csv reader, and can instead use a normal open():

```
import csv

my_file_name = "NVG.txt"
cleaned_file = "cleanNVG.csv"
remove_words = ['INAC','EIM']

with open(my_file_name, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(cleaned_file, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in infile:
        if not any(remove_word in line for remove_word in remove_words):
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Oh okay, but I still need the delimiter '|' since all of the columns are separated by this value. How would I include that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you trying to delete entire rows if the string appears anywhere in the row, or only delete particular columns within the row, leaving the remaining columns unchanged?

Comment: Delete entire rows if the string appears anywhere in the row.

Comment: If that's true you shouldn't need to worry about the '|' in between fields, since you are iterating over lines in the file.